# unfortunately "appname" has stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

i am following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/  for android sdk, every thing went fine as it is described on the given lik, but when i ran my project i got the error "unfortunately 'appname' has stopped working" and here are my logcat errors :

```
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.hellofriend/com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:227)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.Session.<init>(Session.java:216)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.Session$Builder.build(Session.java:1575)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:888)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:830)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
09-26 17:37:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(5849):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks.

And my manifest file is :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="21907****928145"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

here are my new logcat errors :(
    09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.hellofriend/com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4974)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument 'applicationId' cannot be null
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:29)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.Session.(Session.java:227)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.Session.(Session.java:216)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.Session$Builder.build(Session.java:1575)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:888)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.Session.openActiveSession(Session.java:830)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
09-26 18:55:54.564: E/AndroidRuntime(11123):    ... 11 more

Comment: `'applicationId' cannot be null`?

Comment: @RobinHood already have given my app id in string.xml  <string name="app_id">********************</string> if ur talking about another then plz let me know about that thanks.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">hellofriend</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
 <string name="app_id">********</string>
</resources>
are you talking about this one?

Comment: @AamirSaif look at my answer it is solution for this kind of exception when using FB SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add and app id in Your manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
```

above `</application>` tag.

`"@string/fb_app_id"` is Your Fb app id from Facebook Developer Console inside `strings.xml` file.

**EDIT:**

If You are sure that Your manifest looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.hellofriend.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="21907****928145"/>

</application>
```

Try to setup App ID in code:

```
session = new Session(this);
session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId("21907****928145").build();
```

**EDIT : (sample using set app id in code)**

Create new class and put it in main package:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        session = new Session(this);
        session = new Session.Builder(this).setApplicationId("21907****928145").build();
    }
}
```

Rename Your `<application>` `in AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
android:name=".MyApp">
...
```

Comment: I have posted my manifest file , I am getting error on the line where i am giving my app id.

Comment: Change `android:value="@string/21907****928145"` to  `android:value="@string/app_id"` or just `android:value="21907****928145"`

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Swierczek it removed error from manifest but still i am facing the same problem  "unfortunately 'appname' has stopped working"

Comment: I did as u said, but no success yet :(

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ check if u done all proper

Comment: thanks for your replies, my manifest is same as yours,as I am a new developer that's why don't know where can I setup my App Id as you suggested above?

Comment: @AamirSaif I post a code for You. Maybe try to use some Facebook sample project to be sure that it is write correctly and check Your environment setup until it will work?

Comment: Thanks your sample manifest helped me out, I was just doing a silly mistake by putting <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/> before </application> i solved my problem, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the string "@string/21907****928145"

I am guessing you have a String resource with the name "21907****928145" and the app key as value.

The String resource's name can not start with a number.

Comment: I have updated my manifest, check it and let me know what is wrong. i am still facing the same problem of "unfortunately 'appname' has stopped working"

Comment: Try making a string resource with name "AppId" and your app id as value. In your manifest put 
     <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/AppId"/>

Also, not sure if it matters, but I always put it inside the Application and not inside an Activity

Comment: By putting <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/> inside the Application saved my time Thanks @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1373050/mark-buikema